# postgresql: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I don't know how to resolve my situation:

```
create Table VIPUsers(
  id int primary key,
  parent int references Parent(id)
);

create Table Parent(
  id int not null,
  childType int not null,/*indicates ChildA or ChildB*/
  unique (id,childType)
);
create index on Parent(id);

create Table ChildA(
  parent int references Parent(id),
  propertyA int
);

create Table ChildB(
  parent int references Parent(id),
  propertyB date
);
```

There is M to N relationship between tables `VIPUsers` and `ChildA`, `ChildB`.
Table `Parent` is a junction table containing information whether `VIPUsers` uses instances of `ChildA` and/or instances of `ChildB`

I need to add rows:

```
insert into Parent (id,subtype) values (1,1)
insert into Parent (id,subtype) values (1,2)
```

This gave me an error 'duplicate primary key' so I deleted the primary key and I'd use an index instead, just as it is shown above.

But now I can't create tables `VIPUsers`, `ChildA`, `ChildB` as I get the error

```
'there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table ...'
```

I know it is because `VIPUsers` would not reference a unique row. But that's what I need. I need a join where for each parent I get one or more childTypes. For example:

```
  VIPUsers ParentId   childType
    1         1          1
    1         1          2
```

If I make `Parent.id` a primary key, there will be only one `childType` for each user. If I remove primary key, DBMS starts complaining about referencing a non unique column.

My goal is to then cross join the above example table with ChildA or ChildB on ParentId to get table like this:

```
 VIPUsers  ParentId   childType  ChildA.propertyA  ChildB.propertyB 
    1         1          1             50                 null
    1         1          2            null              2/2/2017
```

And based on the `childType` I'm able to tell what kind of information this row represents.

I don't like putting `childType` into each `Child` table because it would allow for nonsense values like ChildA being of type ChildB and vice versa.

What are the usual ways of going about this?

Comment: Did you know that PostgreSQL has inheritance feature? Check  [Inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) section.

Comment: I knew. I didn't want to use it because of the second-last sentence. I think it would do what I don't want.

Comment: @SahapAsci But maybe what you're saying is the only solution.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Parent` and `ChildA` (and ChildB)? One to one? One to many?

Comment: What is the relationship between `ChildA` and `ChildB`? What is the relationship between `VIPUsers` and `ChildA` (and ChildB)? The question is not clear at all about what exactly you want to model. No wonder that the attempted solutions have issues

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Across the 'children' tables, their references to Parent may overlap. So ChildA can refer to the same Parent.Id as ChildB, because VIPUser can use any number of different children. Children tables represent a different kind of problem, so I decided to have separate tables instead of having one which contains all columns. That way I would have to store null values and have many nulls in each row. At the moment I have different tables and the null values I need to get via the appropriate select..join query. Hope this helps.

Comment: I still have no answer to my questions. "VIPUser can use any number of different children." OK, can a VIPUser use children of both types (A and B)? Or just one of them? Can a child be used by many VIPUsers?

Comment: Yes to first question (Not only one of them). Yes to the last question.

Comment: OK. That is clear, about that part. Now the `Parent` table. Is it to store only information about what types a VIPUSer can access/use? (Say vipuser-1 can use only children of typeA but vipuser-2 can use children of both types, etc)? Or is the Parent table used for anything else?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ VIPUser can decide which child or both they want. According to that, Parent will contain the info as you said. Parent cannot contain non unique combination of ID and childtype. Attribute ChildType only helps to interpret rows from childA + childB. But I think it will simply be easiest and even quicker to read from if I just create one big table, which will contain all info from ChildA + ChildB + the childtype column.

Comment: OK, all is a bit more lcear now. I'll post an answer but one last (I hope) question: Did you omit the M-N junction table(s) between VIPUsers and ChildX? I suppose you do have such table(s). You have to store somewhere which VIPUsers has used which child (I suppose that's what you refer as "Used Children" in your answer).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I was considering table Parent as junction table. I could have not considered that I need to add another one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69124/discussion-between-ypercube-and-daniel-katz).

Comment: I don't like my own question, it should be downvoted because I avoided putting forward a concrete situation and I tried to generalize it by modifyting the names of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

After some clarification (in comments and chat), it seems that:

- `ChildA` and `ChildB` are subtypes.
- a `VIPUser` has a many-to-many relationship with all `Child` entities (*"VIPUser "uses" Child"*).
- there is a many-to-many relationship between `VIPUser` and `ChildType` (stored in `Parent`), essentially what types of `Child` a `VIPuser can use (*"VIPUser "can use" a child of ChildType"*).

Then the relationships between entities can be shown in the diagram
(I renamed `Parent` to `VIPCanUse`):

```
               ChildType
VIPUser        /      \
      \       /        \
       \     /          \
      VIPCanUse          \
           \           Child
            \         /    |
             \       /     ------------
              \     /        |        | 
               \   /       ChildA   ChildB
              VipUses
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a wrong schema and the answer is, I should pay a very close attention to what every reference mean, and if this really supports all of the requirements I need.